# NextJS - 400 Bad Request when making multiple API calls but no error when called independently

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-hooks

Let's say I've got these two components:

```
<div>
  <Component1 />
  <Component2 />
</div>
```

Both components are making an API call, using `useEffect`. **If I comment out any of the components, the other one work** **(so they both work independently)**. But if I let both (like above), I'll have 400 Bad Request for both API calls.

I tried to put both components in one but I'm facing the same issue as soon as I make two API calls.

Just in case, here is my `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
const fetchData = async () => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  try {
    const { data } = await (await fetch(`/api/${endpoint}`)).json();
    setData(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
  setIsLoading(false);
};

fetchData();
}, [endpoint]);
```

**I never faced this issue with ReactJS, using the same components.** So I guess it's a bad practice from me which doesn't work with NextJS.

Comment: Can you share the handler for the API in question?